# My URI.parse is not returning an URI::InvalidURIError on an invalid string

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to validate a URL, but my URI.parse is accepting any string without raising an `URI::InvalidURIError` error. Am I doing something wrong?

```
require 'uri'
URI.parse('invalid')
 => #<URI::Generic invalid>
```

**Solution**
I fixed this by checking for the class of the returned object. In the case it's URI::Generic I raise my own error.

Comment: Ok, so I found that it's not an invalid URI... what if I do want it to be an error? Can I raise it manually?

Answer (score 2):

`URI::InvalidURIError` is raised when it can't parse a argument as Object or multibyte characters.

```
irb(main):001:0> url = URI.parse(Object.new)
URI::InvalidURIError: bad URI(is not URI?): #<Object:0x007fcb7c2097a8> 

irb(main):002:0> url = URI.parse('')
URI::InvalidURIError: URI must be ascii only "\u{1f363}"
```

In this case, `invalid` is regarded as `path`.

```
irb(main):003:0> URI.parse('invalid').path
=> "invalid"
```

Comment: Exactly, Object is that  `Object.respond_to?(:to_str)` returns false.

Answer (score 2):

`URI.Parse` works in different way 
If you say `u = URI.parse('http://google.com')`,
you'll get URI::HTTP and the u.port which will be 80 by default.

If you say `u = URI.parse('google.com')`, you'll get a `URI::Generic` back with the `u.port` will be nil.

as a result these will not raise any error

to rais `URI::InvalidURIError` you will have to pass URI as argument of URI.parse

so following code will raise the error

```
require 'uri'
URI.parse(URI('invalid'))
```

Comment: I'm getting an error also for valid links... URI::InvalidURIError: bad URI(is not URI?):

Comment: My bad mainly `URI::InvalidURIError` only fires when you are giving some wrong input in URI. look at the following example 
`URI('inva lid')` this will fire `URI::InvalidURIError`

but if you provide `URI('invalid')` in that case `URI::InvalidURIError` will not fire 

@bo-oz let me know

Comment: True, I fixed it by explicitly checking if the returned object is either URI::HTTP or URI::HTTPS, otherwise raising the error manually.

Answer (score 0):

```
require 'uri'

if url =~ URI::regexp
    # Correct URL
end
```

Comment: this doesn't reject a malformed URL like "htt:/tiktok.com/username"